# Box shadow with transparent layer

Tags: css

I am trying to create a button with box-shadow like below:
[image]

with transparent space between the button and the shadow. How can it be implemented?

Comment: With CSS it might be possible ... did you try it ? If yes, please post your code here. If no, please try it and then post your code here .

Comment: If the shadow is to have a hole in the middle then it is not a shadow of the shape!

Comment: `I am trying to create a button with box-shadow like below:` I don't see any shadow there? `with transparent space between the button and the shadow` it is not exactly clear how this should look like. Please how the final result should look like. And the and a [mcve] of what you already have and explain how that is different to what you want to have.

Comment: Is it that black ‘inner border’ that you want to be transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `box-shadow` is the best approach. You can instead try `outline` css property.

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: 4px solid #aaa;
  outline-offset: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  Action
</div>
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to use outline property. box-shadow itself can be used to achieve the required styling.

Comment: @DreamTek Thanks! I didn't know existed `outline-offset`. Seems like a good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-color: #625e5e;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper button.custom-btn {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 5px transparent solid;
    outline: 5px rebeccapurple solid; 
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.button-wrapper button.custom-btn span {
    border: 0;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    min-width: 115px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    display: block;
    border: 5px transparent solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="custom-btn">
            <span class="">Action</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```